# finding the common elements of vectors which are inside another map

Tags: c++

dear all,
i have a map, defined as `map<int, vector<int> > my_map`. So, for example it looks like as follows,

```
my_map=
0 1 2 6 5 4
1 0 2 3 4 5
2 0 1 4
3 1
4 1 2 0 7 5 6
5 1 0 6 4
6 0 5 4
7 4

vector<int> element_common(map<int, vector<int> > &my_map, int s1, int s2){
     vector<int> common2;
     vector<int> first_vector=my_map[s1];     
     vector<int>::iterator snd_vector_begin= my_map[s2].begin();
     vector<int>::iterator snd_vector_end= my_map[s2].end();          
     for (vector<int>::iterator any=first_vector.begin();
                            any!=first_vector.end();
                            any++){            
         // check if any is in other_list
         vector<int>::iterator any_in_snd_vector_iterator= find (snd_vector_begin,snd_vector_end, *any);            
         if(any_in_snd_vector_iterator==snd_vector_end){
            common2.push_back(*any); 
            }
         }
     return common2;
```

i wrote a function above function to get common elements from the vector parts which are relevant to 2 given keys. when keys are equal to s1 and s2, i.e. s1=1 and s2=4. then my function should give me 0,2,5. but i got 3,4. please help me to rectify my function.

Comment: Any chance you could show your real code, or at least a version which compiles and exhibits the same bad behavior?

Comment: Identifiers can't begin with a number `2nd_vector_begin`. Not sure how this even compiles.

Comment: @shoosh: That was one of the syntax errors I was referring to.  `ommon2.push_back` (missing `c`) is another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the test exactly backwards:

```
if(any_in_2nd_vector_iterator==2nd_vector_end){
```

is true when the element ISN'T FOUND in the second vector.  Try `!=`.

Then, you can avoid needless copying of vectors by using a reference:

```
const vector<int>& first_vector=my_map[s1];
```

and if your vectors get much larger, it may be faster to do a hash lookup (or pre-sorted merge if the vectors are always kept sorted) instead of a call to `find` which has to check every element.

Comment: @ ben, yes, you are right. could you please elaborate your 2nd suggestion (please modify my codes). i am poor in the pointers. please, it will be helping me a lot.

Comment: @g_niro: hash sets will only help if the vectors are large (maybe 100 elements or more).  And I took a closer look and your vectors aren't sorted, so the merge wouldn't work without an expensive sort first.

Comment: again @ ben, thank you very much for the valuable comment, but i wanted to know the modification with const vector<int>& first_vector=my_map[s1]; part as i am poor in this pointer case. if, can show me the modified code by inserting above part.

Comment: @g_niro: That's exactly how the line should look.  It replaces the existing line `vector<int> first_vector=my_map[s1];` (the only change is to add `const` and `&`)

Answer (score 4):

If you can guarantee your vectors are sorted then you can improve your performance substantially from O(mn) to O(m + n):

```
std::vector<int> common;
std::set_intersection(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(),
                      vec2.begin(), vec2.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(common));
```

Comment: thank you pointing fast method. i can sort it before i use the vector1, 2 also.

Comment: General idea's great, but you can't pass common.begin() as an output iterator unless you've allocated a big enough (hard to know what this would be) vector ahead of time.  An insertion iterator's the go.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I meant by "pre-sorted merge", but I didn't know it was included in the standard library.  +1